# Using non-ascii characters in connection string password

Tags: c#, string, ms-access, connection-string, non-ascii-characters

I'm writing a utility to work with a bunch of legacy Access '97 .MDB files.  I need to connect to them programmatically, and I am not allowed to convert the files to a newer version of Access.  So far, no a big deal.  A majority of them are password protected, but the password is really odd:

[image: Password File]

I found out the hard way that making this string the default text for a text box will break my code.  I am able to read the password and load it into a text box on my form with the following code:

```
FileStream Reader = new FileStream(openFileDialog2.FileName, FileMode.Open);
byte[] StringData = new byte[Reader.Length];
Reader.Read(StringData, 0, StringData.Length);
String strPassword = Encoding.Default.GetString(StringData);

txtReadPassword.Text = strPassword;
strDatabasePassword = strPassword;
```

If I write the string out to the console at this point the last character does not appear, but the capitol E with the accent mark does.  I am generating the connection string using the read password via the following code:

```
public static string GetConnectionString(string strDataSource, string strPassword)
        {
            return String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Mode=Share Deny None;data source={0};password={1};", strDataSource, strPassword,"Jet OLEDB:Database ");
        }
```

And the connection string returned does contain the special characters:

[image]

The password is correct, as I can copy/paste it into access and it opens the database.  When I try to use that connection string via this code:

```
private void btnConnectToDatabase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection connection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();

                try
                {
                    connection.ConnectionString = strConnectionString;
                    connection.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to data source" + ex.ToString());
                }
        }
```

I get this result:

[image]

Line 78 is "connection.ConnectionString = strConnectionString;" from above.  Index 137, I believe, is the last two characters in the connection string that are the weird characters in the password.

The "no-longer-supported" application that generated and opens these .MDB files is connecting to them programmatically, so there has to be a way to do so.  The solution has eluded me for three days now, so I'm looking for help.

Comment: Have you tried with unicode: String strPassword = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(StringData);

Comment: I am unable to recreate your issue. My C# application had no problems opening an Access97 database file whose database password was `54BÈ┘`. However, I did have to change the connection string parameter from `;password=54BÈ┘` to `;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=54BÈ┘`, otherwise Jet OLEDB thought that the database had User-Level Security (ULS) enabled and complained about not finding the workgroup information file.

Comment: Gustav, I tried that and the password becomes Chinese characters...and does not work.

Comment: Gord, I changed that section of the connection string to what you posted and the same "does not conform" error listed above with the index reference.  It gives me hope that you were able to connect with an Access 97 database using the same characters in the password.  I'm wondering if I have my project setup incorrectly, or if I am missing an assembly or reference.  Did you add anything beyond the standard template when you started the project?  Could you post the code that you used which actually worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Pierce There are these most awesome specifications by Microsoft for the number of characters in a password depending on the version of Access.  So like the rad thing is that Access 2003 and below are 14 characters and Access 2007+ is 20 characters.  Give the 20 characters a shot since you're using 22 characters in your example. SWEET!

Comment: Kill me in the face!  We double checked the password by converting the database, opening it in 2010 and doing a copy/paste of the password - it worked just fine.  As it turns out Access was TRUNCATING the password to 20 characters, but because it was masked it never registered to me.  I dug up an old install of Access '97 and the copy/paste of the password did NOT work!  If you drop the two final odd characters though, it does!  It was never the code - it was a combination of a bad password and Access throwing us a curve ball when we tested the password for validity by truncating the paste.

Comment: SWEET!  Brewski in one hand, babe in the other, and soak up some mother nature.

Answer (score 0):

For those that still have this problem despite proper password length (up to 14/20 chars), encapsulate the password value inside either apostrophes or escaped quotation marks:

```
"...;Password=\"passwordÈ┘\""
```

or

```
"..;Password='passwordÈ┘'"
```